# How to implement changes of the location and a rest button (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android app dev and Java isn't my strongest programming language.

I able to make my user to allow their location to be access or deny to get their location longitude and latitude number. Though, I still can't figure our how to implement the precision changes of the location to either increase or decrease their coordinate number. I read all the documentation for android in this topic and still don't understand it.

Here's the code:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

public class Locator extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button back;
    private final String enable = "Enable yout location for the GPS to work";
    private final String loading = "GPS is starting";
    private final String latAndLong = "Latitude: %s\n Longitude: %s\n";
    private LocationManager lm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.location);
        back = findViewById(R.id.backbutton);
        back.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Locator.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        });
    }

    public void getLocation(View v) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, getResources().getInteger(R.integer.requestCode));
        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean isProviderEnabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (!isProviderEnabled) {
            Snackbar.make(v, enable, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action",
                    null).show();
        } else {
            userLoca();
        }
    }

    private void userLoca() {
        TextView tvLocation = findViewById(R.id.textView_locator);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Locator.this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            tvLocation.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.location_denied));
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, getResources().getInteger(R.integer.requestCode));
        } else if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Locator.this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            tvLocation.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.location_denied));
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, getResources().getInteger(R.integer.requestCode));
        } else {
            tvLocation = findViewById(R.id.textView_locator);
            Location current_GPS = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            Location networkLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            Location passiveLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);
            if (current_GPS != null) {
                tvLocation.setText(String.format(latAndLong, current_GPS.getLatitude(),
                        current_GPS.getLongitude()));
            }
            if (networkLocation != null) {
                tvLocation.setText(String.format(latAndLong, networkLocation.getLatitude(),
                        networkLocation.getLongitude()));
            }
            if (passiveLocation != null) {
                tvLocation.setText(String.format(latAndLong, passiveLocation.getLatitude(),
                        passiveLocation.getLongitude()));
            } else {
                Snackbar.make(tvLocation, loading, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action",
                        null).show();
                lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                        getResources().getInteger(R.integer.location_min_time),
                        getResources().getInteger(R.integer.location_min_dist), v -> {
                        });
                lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        getResources().getInteger(R.integer.location_min_time),
                        getResources().getInteger(R.integer.location_min_dist), v -> {
                        });
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement location updates listener to this. Use the following code:

```
private LocationCallback locationCallback;
```

Call this in *onCreate()* or *onResume()* depending upon your logic

```
locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
        if (locationResult == null) {
            return;
        }
        for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
            // Update UI with location data
            // ...
        }
    }
};

private void startLocationUpdates() {
    fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,
            locationCallback,
            Looper.getMainLooper());
}
```